# The $abc$ conjecture as a special case of Vojta's height inequality

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abc-conjecture

From [Quanta](https://www.quantamagazine.org/titans-of-mathematics-clash-over-epic-proof-of-abc-conjecture-20180920/) I've learned that Peter Scholze and Jakob Stix [rejected](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Emotizuki/SS2018-08.pdf) Shinichi Mochizuki's proof of the $abc$ conjecture in September 2018.

As a non-expert one stumbles a little earlier than necessary over the introductory paragraphs of Scholze/Stix' paper:

> [image]

While Masser-Oesterlé's Conjecture 1 (the $abc$ conjecture itself) is explicitly given and quite easy to understand, it's not at all clear (to the non-expert) what Vojta's height inequality says, and why and in which sense Conjecture 1 is a special case of it.

> Please help me to see why and how the $abc$ conjecture is a special
> case of Vojta's height inequality for the projective line
> $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the divisor $D = 0 + 1 + \infty$*.

What especially do **for**, **with respect to**, and **divisor** $D = 0 + 1 + \infty$ mean in this context?

(Please assume that I know what the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$ is.)

Comment: [here](http://www.msri.org/attachments/workshops/301/HtSurveyMSRIJan06.pdf) are some notes on Height functions...Vojta's conjecture is discussed in one chapter.